# osx can't install webpack due to missing dependency

Tags: macos, npm, webpack

Is nobody else getting this?

```
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.3
node-pre-gyp info using node@11.15.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/aaa/Documents/projects/sweetalert/node_modules/canvas-prebuilt/canvas/build/Release/canvas-prebuilt.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/chearon/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v1.6.11/canvas-prebuilt-v1.6.11-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://github.com/chearon/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v1.6.11/canvas-prebuilt-v1.6.11-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! install error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/chearon/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v1.6.11/canvas-prebuilt-v1.6.11-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/aaa/Documents/projects/sweetalert/node_modules/canvas-prebuilt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/install.js:137:27)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:198:15)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (/Users/aaa/Documents/projects/sweetalert/node_modules/request/request.js:1066:10)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:193:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:560:23)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:113:17)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:447:22)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:193:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:276:11)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.0.0
```

I can't install webpack because of fsevents installation failing because of the missing node-canvas-prebuilt.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation via Homebrew seems outdated as it tries to install version 1.6.11 of `canvas-prebuilt`, which was released around 2017 and is not anymore available. The closest version to it is 1.6.15.

I would recommend you follow the installation instructions from [the official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/) to install it via `npm` on a per-project basis:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
# or for a one-liner just do npm i webpack webpack-cli
```

Note it is *not* recommended to install WebPack globally (`npm i -g webpack`) but to install it for each of your projects so different versions of the tool can be used in parallel. This will make your life easier in the future when using WebPack with projects from various development times.

Comment: This is what I did when I got the error. I may have installed node at one point with homebrew but it was many years ago. I've since deleted and reinstalled node many times, not with homebrew. Is the homebrew installation still mucking things up in the background?

Comment: `aaas-iMac:sweetalert aaa$ npm i webpack webpack-cli
⸨            ░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ extract:fsevents: sill extract fsevents@1.1.2 extracted to /Users/aaa/Documents/projects/sweetalert/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-c05831a9 (2616ms)`

Stuck here.

Comment: I also tried installing in a windows VM on parallels desktop and got the same thing, stuck on fsevents@1.1.2. Strange?

Comment: Have you ensured the path where the project is created is accessible without an elevated prompt @Harry?

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: When installing packages with npm for a project you will firstly need to create a folder for the project. For example, do `cd ~/Desktop && mkdir MyProject && cd MyProject && npm i webpack webpack-cli`

Comment: darn, so that's fine but no project I clone from github is fine.

Comment: Where do you clone the GitHub projects @Harry? Could you try as well on desktop?